# How do i get result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

**I need SUM of this result:**

```
SELECT 
  ROUND(
    (invoicesitems.pscost / invoicesitems.inmedunit -
     AVG(ISNULL(mainexstock.peacecost,0)) / invoicesitems.inmedunit), 2)
  *
  CASE WHEN units.unitqty=3 THEN (invoicesitems.bigqty *
    invoicesitems.inbigunit * invoicesitems.inmedunit) +
    (invoicesitems.medqty * invoicesitems.inmedunit) + 
    invoicesitems.smallqty 
       ELSE (invoicesitems.bigqty * invoicesitems.inmedunit) 
             + invoicesitems.smallqty 
  END AS PROFITS 
FROM invoicesitems 
INNER JOIN mainexstock ON mainexstock.pid = invoicesitems.pid 
INNER JOIN units ON units.[uid] = invoicesitems.punits 
WHERE invoicesitems.bid = 'B-0480580' 
GROUP BY
  invoicesitems.pid, invoicesitems.inbigunit,
  invoicesitems.inmedunit, invoicesitems.bigqty, 
  invoicesitems.medqty, invoicesitems.smallqty, 
  invoicesitems.pscost, units.unitqty
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL management studio 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as a CTE and get the sum. For example:

```
with a as (
  -- your big query here
)
select sum(profits) as profits from a;
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon